# see the list of event listeners currently attached

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to check the list of event listeners that are added. For example, I used the code `cy.on('pan zoom resize', update);` and added function called `update` in for loop. I do this many times. I also call `cy.off('pan zoom resize', update);` to remove the event listeners but I want to be sure about it.

The only think I can think of is using `console.log` but this method might not be helpful.

I also think that in some places people forgot to remove the event listeners and just always added. With too many repetitions this might cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a data field in the private cytoscape object called `listeners`. You can see that if you:

- `console.log()` the cy object,
- navigate to `_private`,
- then open the `emitter` object
- and lastly go to `listeners`

[image]

This is the array listing all the default and user defined event listeners with some metadata like the event, type and scope of the listener.

You can access this in your code by simply calling

```
cy.emitter().listeners
```

The question now is, why do you need this information in the first place? Normally, you should be just fine if you call `cy.off('eventXY', ...)` before using any `cy.on('eventXY', ...)`. Are you sure you need this for your application to work? Maybe elaborate more on the core problem  (why you want these information in the first place).

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: For me, I just wanted to check if things were robust. I don't want to remove all of the listeners with `cy.off('event')` because some other people might have added listeners. When I remove event listener with `cy.off('eventXY', ...)` I suspect there might be some issues with keeping a reference to a function. For example, if you use debouncing https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function or `fn.bind(this)` references changes. Thanks for the answer